# If a Klein bottle covers a manifold $M$, then $M$ is the Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, klein-bottle

I have to prove that if a Klein bottle covers a manifold $M$, then $M$ is the Klein bottle.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $K\to M$ is a covering, with $K$ a Klein bottle. Then $M$ is a compact surface. If the degree of the covering is $d$, we have that $\chi(K)=d\cdot\chi(M)$, with $\chi(M)$ and $\chi(K)$ the Euler characteristics of $M$ and $K$, respectively. Since $\chi(K)=0$ (and, of course, $d\neq0$) we have $\chi(M)=0$.

The classification of compact surfaces implies then that $M$ is either a torus or a Klein bottle.

But if $M$ were a torus, it would be orientable, and a standard property of covering spaces would then tell us that $K$ is itself orientable, which it isn't.

Therefore $M$ is a Klein bottle, as we wanted it to be.